# Pairing key / values arrays

Tags: javascript, node.js

Consider two arrays. One with keys. The other with values.

Output is an object made of key/value pairs.

Is there better(performance) method to do this than:

```
var keys = ["some", "key", "foo", "bar"];
var values = ["this", "are", "values", "dude"];

var result = { };

for(var i = 0, len = keys.length; i < len; i++) {
  result[keys[i]] = values[i];
}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Have you found this to be a performance bottleneck? If not, why do you care?

Comment: Because I am invoking this 500.000 times per one loop

Comment: Well, direct property access (what you're doing now) will probably be as fast as you can get unless the keys will always be the same.

Comment: Why do you want it convert in key value pair? You can get corresponding value from second array eg. for key 'foo', value = values[keys.indexOf('foo')];

Comment: It would depend on whether he's more concerned about the speed of building this object, or the speed of accessing it later; direct property access is practically O(1) (once you've built the object, which is O(N)), while .indexOf('foo') is O(N) w.r.t. the keys array.

Comment: @Shusl - Upgrade this comment to an answer and I will choose it as a correct one. I am writing a database built on native arrays.

Comment: @rezoner: I don't think JavaScript is the right language for writing a DBS, except you have some very low-level API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` method of array to get corresponding value from second array eg. for key 'foo', value = values[keys.indexOf('foo')];

```
var keys = ["some", "key", "foo", "bar"],
values = ["this", "are", "values", "dude"],
key = 'foo',
value =  values[keys.indexOf('foo')];
```

Comment: As I mentioned above, be aware of the suboptimal running time of this method of accessing the `value`. `keys.indexOf('foo')` runs in O(N) time with respect to the `keys` array, which means that - on average - it takes about as long to run as it would to loop through the entire `keys` array once.

Comment: Yes I am aware, that's why I am going to map keys before invoking the loop. However thanks are going to both of you guys.

Answer (score 0):

http://underscorejs.org  used for the following

```
_.object(keys, values)
```

O(N) complexity for the build, O(1) complexity for the retrieval.. I don't believe that you can beat that if retrieval is your goal.

Comment: looking at the documentation, wouldn't you just need `_.object(keys, values)`?